# Is there any other way to improve Azure CDN latency?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I'm trying to improve the latency of CDN. The particular website will be accessed all over the world. Earlier the website wasn't provided using CDN but because of the slowness, used CDN but still getting the JS file from the CDN is very slow for two people on the same part of the world. I am not talking about accessing on the first time. It is happening randomly very often.

Answer (score 2):

If it happens randomly very often, it sounds like there's something wrong with your caching settings.

To confirm that a file is actually coming from CDN, investigate the network traffic in your browser. If the file came from CDN it will have a "X-Cache: HIT" response header.

If you can't reproduce it yourself, click a "Manage" button in your CDN profile. It will open a management window for your CDN and there you can see total "hits" and "misses" for your files, if there's a lot of misses, that will indicate you are having a lot of files not going through CDN and should investigate your caching settings.

Also you should see if your files come out from CDN compressed. Based on your CDN and server settings, it's possible that uncompressed files are cached in the CDN.

If everything looks ok, a way to speed up Azure CDN is to use Dynamic Site Acceleration in addition to caching. It helps with potentially faster SSL negotiation and other network improvements. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-dynamic-site-acceleration

Comment: Okay thanks for the info.I'll look in to the things that you mentioned.

Comment: @ARxAR Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @ARxAR Which pricing tier you are using? We recently changed from Verizon Standard to Microsoft's CDN, and now every miss takes a lot longer and there seems to be more misses